# How to get autocomplete value on the behalf of multiple criteria with jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

I have two fields one is 'designation' and another is 'assign whom' in my html form. What i need to do that provide a list of auto fill value in assign whom field on the changes of designation.
For that I am doing as:-

```
$('#designation').change(function(){
    var desg = $(this).val();
    if(desg) {
        $( "#assign_whom" ).autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url:"assign_whom.php", // from this page I get the data list in the form of json.
                    data: {term:request.term,desg:$('#designation').val()},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {
                        response(data);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 1,
            focus: function( event, ui ) {
            return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
            document.getElementById('assign_to').value=ui.item.id;
            return true;
            }
        });         
    }
});
```

But still I am stuck and required auto list not showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#designation').change(function(){
    var desg = $(this).val();
    if(desg) {
        $( "#assign_whom" ).autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url:"assign_whom.php", // from this page I get the data list in the form of json.
                    data: {term:request.term,desg:$('#designation').val()},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(fdata) {
                         response($.map(fdata, function (item) {
                                return { label: item.displayvalue, value: item.value};
                            }));
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 1,
            focus: function( event, ui ) {
            return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
            document.getElementById('assign_to').value=ui.item.id;
            return true;
            }
        });         
    }
});
```